# KENDO UI : Invalid Template Format

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I am very new to Kendo ui, and I am trying to create a template but I am getting the `"Invalid template"` error. What I want to achieve is to check if the field name is valid (exists on the current object) so I can avoid the `undefined property` error.

```
template: "<div><input type='checkbox' value='#=" + field + "?#= "+ field +":\"\"#'/>#=" + field + "?#="+ field +":\"\"#</div>"
```

I am trying to reproduce the reproduce this example `http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/checkbox-filter-menu` , but some objects of data I have, does not contain some properties.

Comment: You can use `typeof` to check if property exists in model. If it does not  exists, when it will return `undefined`. However, I am not sure what are you trying to do, because kendo ui sample is working and checks for field names where to apply this filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use if/else instead of the ?: operator.

So adapting on that [Kendo Example](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/checkbox-filter-menu) you mentioned, the below snippet uses the value of "field" if it exists otherwise places the alternative "\", which is what I think you were trying to achieve above

```
template: "<div><input type='checkbox' #if("+field+"){# value='#:" + field + "#'/>#:" + field + "#</div>#}else{#value='\'/> \</div>#}#"
```

Alternatively the following template won't create an element at all if "field" doesn't exist:

```
template: "#if("+field+"){# <div><input type='checkbox' value='#:" + field + "#'/>#:" + field + "#</div> #}#"
```

For reference see the Template Syntax section here:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview